# Using tidyr gather function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I've been spending ages trying to transform a particular data frame into a long format. The data frame looks like this: 
[image: Data frame 1].

I generated it using the following code:

```
wide <-
panel2 %>%
select(Panelist, Income, Age, Education) %>% filter(Panelist < 1100500)
wide
```

My goal is to transform the data frame into this:

[image: Data frame 2]

Is there anyone that can help me with this? I'm lost on what to do...

Comment: Please share your example data and desired output as reproducible form. You can use `dput` to achieve that.

Comment: `%>% gather(key = Demographics, value = value, Income, Age, Education)`

Comment: To expand on www's comment: I'm generally willing to help but usually not if it requires *transcribing data from images*. There are times when it is meaningful to show an image of a `data.frame`, but I believe they are few and far-between.

Comment: Links may break and this question relies heavily on them. It would be useful to transcribe their content so that the question stays relevant (and as r2evans points out, others can copy the code). =)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I will transcribe my data frame next time, sorry about that. @Vlo , your answer worked for me!